# Qt Debugger show Segmentation Fault when debugging a given Qt example

Tags: qt, gdb, segmentation-fault

I am debugging `"examples/itemviews/simpletreemodel"` example.

In the main.cpp file line

```
view.setWindowTitle(QObject::tr("Simple Tree Model"));
```

Causes debugger to show segmentation fault. If I comment out this line and run debugger again it goes through fine. If I run in normal mode (no debug) it goes through fine.

What could be the problem? I am using Qt 4.7.4 with gdb 7.3.1 debugger.

I am using `setWindowTitle` in a separate program and it causes debugger to break there as well.

Comment: Why -1? I don't quite understand!

Comment: Yeah, the -1 is a little harsh. Anyway, your issue sounds like a problem with your Qt installation (or how your linking to your qt installation). Do you happen to have two versions of qt on your comp? Also, could you post a full stack trace of the seg fault?

Comment: Actually I do have multiple installations of Qt on linux server. I have set my QTDIR to point to a 4.7.4 version of Qt. However what you are saying could be true. Because when I run my debugger without any breakpoints it goes through fine I get the output mainwindow also. However as soon as I put a breakpoint in main.cpp I start getting weird errors like  `tcsh: symbol lookup error: tcsh: undefined symbol: STRnoclober` and `tcsh: symbol lookup error: tcsh: undefined symbol: pnoprcesses` . I am not getting seg fault anymore. Something random is happening.